# Evaluating $\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$

Tags: combinatorics, infinite-product

I was studying for some quizzes when wild question appears. It looks like this:

Find $\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$

**My work**

I think it's a repeated multiplication of the expression $1-\frac{1}{k^2}$. It looks like this:

$$\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \left(1-\frac{1}{(2)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(3)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(3)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(4)^2}\right).....$$

I barely had any experience evaluating these new summation...How do evaluate $\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$?

Comment: Try to find out what happens if $k=6$ (a small value of $k$). Much of the staff you have is canceled.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas What do you mean "Much of the staff you have is canceled"? additional information is lost when I do the operation above?

Comment: Look at the numerators and the denominators in Gerhard's answer below.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas What topic in math do I learn this truth? because I just found this question during our review for some licensure exams....

Answer (score 6):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac1{k^2}\right)\\
&=&\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}\\
&=&\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot 2}\cdot\frac{2\cdot4}{3\cdot3}\cdot\frac{3\cdot5}{4\cdot 4}\cdot\ldots\\
&=&\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{k+1}{2\cdot k}\\
&=&\frac12
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: wow! what topic in math deals with questions like mine?